# Inserting into database by reading another

Tags: mysql, split

I have a database X which containst tables Y and Z. In Y, I have a column called W. It contains data seperated by a comma. What I want to do, is go trough Y, split data in W and insert it into Z if it doesn't exists.

I'm using MySQL database. Help?

Edit. To be more specific I give you a bit more information. W can contain items seperated by a comma from zero to hundreds. I want the code to check if them exists in Z. If they doesn't it will insert them in Z, every one splitted by a comma in their own records. So, data "a,b,c" in W would look like "a", "b", "c" in Z, all in their own records.

Comment: ok, starting over since the other comments got deleted... There can be a lot of values in W and you need one row in Z for each value in W, is that correct? Also is using a script in some language an option?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. And yes, I can use PHP.

Comment: if for example Z has 3 columns (z1,z2,z3) for W='a,b,c' there will be one row in Z with z1='a',z2='b',z3='c' or 3 rows in Z like (z1=a,z2=null,z3=null),(z1=b,z2=null,z3=null),(z1=c,z2=null,z3=null)

Comment: The last one is what I want, though in Z there's columns id and value.

Answer (score 2):

this should do it after you put the proper host,user,pass,db,tables...

```
<?php

$conn = new mysqli('some_host', 'some_user', 'some_pass', 'some_db');

if ($conn->connect_error) die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '. $mysqli->connect_error);

$zrows = array();

$result = $conn->query("SELECT W FROM Y");

if($result) while ($row = $result->fetch_object()){
    if(!empty($row->W)) foreach(explode(',',$row->W) as $v) $zrows[] = "('".$conn->real_escape_string($v)."')";

}
if(!empty($zrows)) {
    $conn->query("INSERT IGNORE INTO Z (`value`) VALUES ".implode(',',$zrows));
}
```

if there are too many rows you may hit PHP's memory limit or mysql's max_packet_size in which case you can insert records a few 1000's at a time

Also forgot that you need to have a `UNIQUE KEY` on `value` in `Z`

Comment: Sorry, I had to take the answer mark away, because I didn't get it work. At least it seemed working for a day :D As I said earlier, I have id and value in Z. ID is AUTO INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, and value is PRIMARY KEY (ALTER TABLE Z ADD PRIMARY KEY(id,value)) and when I run the code, I get multiple duplicates. It seems I have a total of over 400 values in W column and there is about 25 different. Now I'm getting all the over 400 in the database - all of them as their own records. Some more help, please?

Comment: ALTER TABLE Z ADD PRIMARY KEY(id,value) does not create an unique key on 'value'. Check out [the mysql manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html).

Comment: I tried ALTER TABLE Z ADD PRIMARY KEY(id). setting id AUTO_INCREMENT and value UNIQUE, but I'm still getting multiple values and the ids won't start from zero and increase..

Comment: No one? Of couse I could just search the database and insert only if no matches found, but that's a lot of queries!

Comment: `ALTER TABLE Z ADD UNIQUE INDEX value (value);` you will need to delete the duplicate records before you add the index.

Comment: What? But then I have about 500 records there and only 25 are unique.

Comment: I don't understand the problem.

Comment: Well, when there are ways to avoid the insert when there's already the same record in the table, why would I go those trough those 500 records and delete the extra 470? What's the point of the index, if I already have all the data in the table?