# Migrate data from non Normalized database to a well Design database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am migrating reads from a poorly design table to the newly Normalize one in sqlserver 2008.
My goal here is to get a count of total record in the Source table store in in a variable.  The loop through each row and insert to the destination table. I have made  numerous search on similar posts:

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616729/inserting-into-database-by-reading-another): [How do I insert a record from one table into another table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18320236/how-do-i-insert-a-record-from-one-table-into-another-table) and [Inserting into database by reading another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616729/inserting-into-database-by-reading-another)

But was able to modify a code from [SQL Examples](http://www.fincher.org/tips/General/SQL.shtml)
Now am get this error:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 5   
Invalid column name 'Num_Row_in_table
```

Code:

```
DECLARE @i INT
DECLARE @Num_Row_in_table int

SET @i=1
WHILE(@i <= Num_Row_in_table)
BEGIN
 Insert into Destinationtable (FirstName,LastName,Photo,SN)
  (
 Select FirstName,LASTNAME,Photo,SN From MyDB.dbo.sourcetable
  )
 SET @i=@i+1
END
```

Comment: Shouldn't you add a `@` in front of the `Num_Row_in_table` as well? `WHILE(@i <= @Num_Row_in_table)`

Comment: @BenjaminDiele, when i remove that i got this error:Msg 155, Level 15, State 2, Line 3
'int' is not a recognized CURSOR option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget the cursor; just do this:

```
Insert into Destinationtable (FirstName,LastName,Photo,SN)
Select FirstName,LASTNAME,Photo,SN From MyDB.dbo.sourcetable
```